# How to share a GIT branch without history? (Using GitLab)

Tags: git, gitlab

I work on a private GitLab and I have multiple branches.
I want to share a single branch with an external developer.

This developer is allowed to read or write on this branch only.
He is not allowed to see the history of any of my other branches.

(I want to merge his work to my branches periodically.)

Is it possible to do this with GitLab?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: You can merge any branch into any branch in your repository.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to declare a new empty repo on gitlab, and add a remote url to your local repo.

That means:

- you can push your branch to that second gitlab repo,
- the other developer can clone that second repo and work with it,
- you can pull from the second repo, and puqh to the first in order to update that shared branch.

The idea remains: you can protect branch against push (write), but not against read, hence the second repo.

Comment: Will this allow the user to isolate a new history (that is, history begins with the first commit), or will it still contain all of the original history back to the initial commit, although it contains any other branches?  It sounds like the second (since removal of history would wreck havoc on the hashes), but I'm curious if it is possible to do the first.  Perhaps something with graft points?

Comment: @zebediah49 yes, by default, it contains everything. To only contain the last few commit, you could cheery-pick the right commit onto an orphan branch (`git branch --root`), and push that branch onto the second repo. Then you can cherry-pick back the commit you want (when you update that smaller branch from the second repo) into your original branch.